# Windows 7 - Said There Were Updates But Then There Were Not

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I do not let any updates install automatically but run "Check for Updates" from "Windows Update" regularly. Yesterday I ran it on a Windows 7 desktop (a number of updates were installed a week previously) and it said there were 8 updates - from what I recall they related to security updates for Outlook, Office and Word and, I think, one for Skype.

When I selected to install them they started downloading and about 25% of the way through Windows Update seemed to bomb out. A "Check for Updates" says there are none available and "View update history" said none were installed. So where did the eight updates go to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, run Windows Update Troubleshooter to check. Download it below.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027322/windows-windows-update-troubleshooter

Then run the System Update Readiness tool.
For Windows 7, download and run the appropriate version of the System Update Readiness Tool.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947821/fix-windows-update-errors-by-using-the-dism-or-system-update-readiness

Reset the Windows Update Components

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971058

Also you could check the WindowsUpdate log in C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log

Comment: Later that day I ran "Check for updates" and it advised me of "Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool - October 2017 (KB890830)" was an important update. After this had been installed the system wanted a reboot. This took a while as it configured updates both when shutting down and restarting.Afterwards the missing eight updates were there so it looks as if something very strange happened. I have noted your answer for future reference.